# local ArcGIS WebAppBuilder cannot find widget settings files

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-js-api, arcgis-server

I have added a widget to the /widgets directory.

I have /widgets/MyWidget/Widget.js and /widgets/MyWidget/setting/Setting.js

Somehow when I try to add the widget the server responds with a not found to the request for Setting.js during the widget configuration stage.

If I just put the raw url into the address bar:
The server can find /widgets/MyWidget/Widget.js but not /widgets/MyWidget/setting/Setting.js